# Is it safe to drill a hole in an Apple TV (3rd gen) remote?

Tags: appletv, remote-control, children

I'm not talking about the end where the buttons are, but rather the other side. This device gets lost several times a day by children who hold on to it and misplace it on a regular basis. What I want to do is attach a hub cap to it like gas stations do with bathroom keys.

Is there anything at the back end of these remotes? I just want to drill a 1/4" hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look around the web for disassembly. From a quick look, it appears there is room to drill a hole below the battery for the silver remote.

The newer generation black remote is much more contained, but there is room in the bottom corners of the remote below the battery.

I'd recommend disassembling and removing adjacent parts before drilling.

Update: Very late reply but for the TV2 remote it should be an all-aluminum body below the battery. I drilled a 1/8" hole through the bottom left.

[image: Remote]

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be very little information on the remote on the web; I think I found ONE picture showing mangled parts and a shell. However, it doesn't quite answer if the bottom half of the remote is just a piece of aluminum or if there is something down there. As well, taking the components out appears to be a one-way street :-/

Answer (score 0):

Any infrared remote can be used with Apple TV - so I might put the nice one in a drawer and get whatever large plastic remote you prefer and do the one time setup to map the existing buttons to the Apple TV functions.

On mono price, a 10 button remote is going for $1.50 and you can double the button count for another quarter or so.

- http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6166
- http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6167

Also, even if you sort out where it's safe to drill - I would go with a very strong adhesive pad over drilling to put a long leash or whatnot on the Apple remote if you choose to go that way.

Comment: Also, eBay has dozens and dozens of keychain and full candy bar remotes to hit the less than $1 and less than $2 price point.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that you could use a product like Sugru or Polymorph to form a piece of plastic onto or around the remote with a piece of metal coat hanger wire embedded to create a loop for you to tie onto.

Answer (score 0):

I drilled a hole into the apple tv 1 remote and it worked fine. I drilled it at the bottom right corner then used a key ring attaching  the remote to a tile finder. But now the new one is all black and even harder  to see sometimes. I am sure there are many ways to figure this out but my idea seems most elegant. I want to get more info on Billy's experience or hear of others who dare to take the chance.

Answer (score -1):

YES I have drilled a hole in the bottom corner and remote works fine.